# Column 'Sites.IsMobileSite' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I have following query. It is giving me an error "Column 'Sites.IsMobileSite' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." for following sql code -

```
 select max(rc.[name]) [Reseller], max(c.[name]) [Customer],    
        case 
            when max(c.[Url]) is not null then max(c.[URL])
            else 'NA'
        end[URL],   
        case 
            when max(s.[Domain]) is not null then max(s.[Domain])
            else 'NA'
        end[Site Name],
        case 
        when (s.[IsMobileSite]) = 0 then 'No'
        else 'Yes'
        end [Is Mobile Site],
        case 
            when max(s.[CreatedDate]) is not null then max(s.  [CreatedDate])               
        end[Created Date]
    from customers c with(nolock)       
    left outer join Sites s with(nolock) on c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId         
    left outer join customers rc on rc.CustomerId = c.ResellerId
    where c.[name] is not null
    and ( c.customerId is null or rc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
    and c.IsActive !=''
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve - I'm immediately suspicious that everything in the `SELECT` list is inside a `MAX()` wrapper. Could you edit your question and give some sample data and the expected results please?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Damien, the code is not clear enough to show what you are trying to do and it doesn't really make sense to have every returned column in a max wrapper. However to remove your error you need to wrap IsMobileSite in a max wrapper:

```
    when ( max(s.[IsMobileSite])) = 0 then 'No'
    else 'Yes'
    end [Is Mobile Site],
```

or group by it:

```
 select max(rc.[name]) [Reseller], max(c.[name]) [Customer],    
    case 
        when max(c.[Url]) is not null then max(c.[URL])
        else 'NA'
    end[URL],   
    case 
        when max(s.[Domain]) is not null then max(s.[Domain])
        else 'NA'
    end[Site Name],
    case 
    when (s.[IsMobileSite]) = 0 then 'No'
    else 'Yes'
    end [Is Mobile Site],
    case 
        when max(s.[CreatedDate]) is not null then max(s.  [CreatedDate])               
    end[Created Date]
from customers c with(nolock)       
left outer join Sites s with(nolock) on c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId         
left outer join customers rc on rc.CustomerId = c.ResellerId
where c.[name] is not null
and ( c.customerId is null or rc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
and c.IsActive !='' 
GROUP BY s.[IsMobileSite]
```

Also instead of all those case statements coalesce will do the job instead, it returns the first non null item from the list supplied to it:

```
coalesce(max(c.[Url]), 'NA') [URL],
```

This will return max(c.[Url]) if it is not null, otherwise it will return 'NA'

IF you just want to return the first row that matches the select criteria then just do something like this:

```
SELECT  TOP 1
    rc.name Reseller,
    c.name Customer,
    COALESCE(c.Url, 'NA') URL,
    COALESCE(s.domain, 'NA') [Site Name],
    CASE
        WHEN s.IsMobileSite = 0 THEN  'No'
        ELSE 'YES'
    END [Is Mobile Site],
    s.CreatedDate
FROM customers c WITH(nolock)
JOIN Sites s WITH(nolock)
ON c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId    
LEFT JOIN customers rc 
ON rc.CustomerId = c.ResellerId
WHERE c.name IS NOT NULL
AND ( c.customerId is null OR rc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
AND c.IsActive !=''
```